# Iterating Over a Dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am trying to return all the values in a dictionary that have a value greater than the int argurment.

```
def big_keys(dict, int):
    count = []
    for u in dict:
        if u > int:
            count.append(u)
    return count
```

I don't understand why this isn't working. It returns every value in the list rather than just those which are greater than in.

Comment: Don't override builtin variables like `int`, `dict`, `str`, `list`...

Answer (score 7):

By default, any dict will iterate over its keys, not its values:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> for i in d:
...    print i
... 
a
b
```

To iterate over values, use `.values()`:

```
>>> for i in d.values():
...    print i
... 
1
2
```

With that in mind, your method can be simplified:

```
def big_keys(d, i):
   return [x for x in d.values() if x > i]
```

I have changed your variable names, since `dict` and `int` are both built-ins.

Your method is actually recreating default functionality available in Python. The `filter` method does what you are trying to do:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 6, 'd': 7, 'e': 0}
>>> filter(lambda x: x > 5, d.values())
[6, 7]
```

---

From your comment it seems you are looking for the *keys* and not the values. Here is how you would do that:

```
>>> d = {'a': 21, 'c': 4, 'b': 5, 'e': 30, 'd': 6, 'g': 4, 'f': 2, 'h': 20}
>>> result = []
>>> for k,v in d.iteritems():
...    if v > 20:
...       result.append(k)
...
>>> result
['a', 'e']
```

Or, the shorter way:

```
>>> [k for k,v in d.iteritems() if v > 20]
['a', 'e']
```

Comment: Thank you. This all makes sense to me but when I run this for a given dict, say {'a': 21, 'c': 4, 'b': 5, 'e': 30, 'd': 6, 'g': 4, 'f': 2, 'h': 20}
and the integer argument is 20 I get a result of ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']. When what I expect is ['a', 'e']. That's what I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 2):

iterating dictionary yields keys for the dictionary.

```
>>> d = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
>>> for x in d:
...     print(x)
...
key2
key1
```

To get values, use `dict.values()`:

```
>>> for x in d.values():
...     print(x)
...
value2
value1
```

So, you program should read as follow:

```
def big_keys(dict, int):
    count = []
    for u in dict.values():
        if u > int:
            count.append(u)
    return count
```